# Logging nginx rate-limited IPs into a specific file

Tags: nginx, synchronization, rate-limiting

I'm looking for an approach to synchronize rate-limited IPs between nginx nodes.
I want to log these IPs and after that pushing them into a database and developing an agent to update blocked IPs in nginx config files.

My challenge is to find a way to have IPs nginx limited with `429` status code.

So, Is it possible to log rate-limited IPs into an specific file in nginx or do you suggest any other approach to synchronize rate-limited IPs between nodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, and a similar example is even in the [nginx documentation](https://nginx.org/r/access_log).

The `access_log` directive also takes an optional `if=` parameter which evaluates variables given to it, and logs only if the result is not 0 or an empty string. Combined with the fact that you can have more than one `access_log` in a level, you can log differently based on your needs.

First, though, you will need a `map` to map the [HTTP response status](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_status) you are interested in to a variable. Remember that `map` must be outside the `server` block.

```
map $status $rate_limited {
    default 0;
    429     1;
}
```

Then in the relevant `server` block you will declare your `access_log`.

```
access_log /var/log/nginx/rate_limited.log combined if=$rate_limited;
```

Remember that any appearance of `access_log` in one level overrides all others from higher levels, so you will want to copy (or better, `include`) the `access_log` directives from higher levels that you also want to use.

Comment: Thank you! For sure, I have to define different access_log formats. Thank you for your useful tips :)